# Slot-filling fills multiple slots at once and makes a mess with strings like "13:00"

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an intent with three required slots (let's call them: `slot_a`, `slot_b`, `slot_c`) all of type `@sys.number`. When the intent gets detected the system prompts me asking for the missing slots:

> What's `slot_a`?

me: 1

> What's `slot_b`?

me: 2

> What's `slot_c`?

me: 3

And this works well. Problems start when I add speech-to-text, because sometimes the system understands "1:00", "2:00", "3:00" instead of simple numbers, and when those are given to dialogflow it behaves like this:

> What's `slot_a`?

me: 1 (but get converted as "1:00")

dialogflow splits "1" and "00", and assigns "1" to `a` and "0" to `b`.

> What's `slot_c`?

me: 3 (but get converted as "3:00")

dialogflow had `b` already so it asked directly for `c`.

This is happening with `it-IT` locale, and I don't know how to fight it. Having it converting "1" to "1:00" is the first half of the problem, but I could work around it in the fulfillment, but then dialogflow splits on `:` and doesn't give me any chance to input the next missing slot.

**EDIT**
Adding a screenshot of the intent:

[image]

I've used the *Try it now* area on the right, writing:

1. "whatever" (to trigger the intent)
2. "1:00" (to fill the `slot_a` as the system prompted me to do)

The result is that `slot_b` was also filled with "0", and now it's asking me to fill `slot_c`, and I have no way to input the real `slot_b`.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the Intent that is supposed to be matched? Given the description, it is hard to understand what is happening.

Comment: @Prisoner done, it's a toy example obviously but the behaviour is the same I'm experiencing on my real one

Comment: It sounds like the *real* problem is that whatever you're saying is converted in stt as "1:00". What *exactly* are you saying? Which stt are you using and how are you using it? (That might be better asked as a separate question, now that I think about it.)

Comment: tts is done direclty by the `detectIntent` API (used through nodejs-dialogflow), the language code is correct and I'm happy with the overall quality of the conversion, but numbers in the range [2-24] *fail* frequently (yea, even though I've used "1" in the example, "1" is actually recognized correclty). What I'm saying is exactly just the number, no grammatical article, nothing else. In italian, well... that may be ambiguous, but anyone's first interpretaion of it whould be "the number" not "the time". Does dialogflow's tts consider slots types during the conversion?

Comment: "The Detect Intent API" was what I was looking for there to see if we could reproduce.

Comment: As soon as I will have time to get back on this I'll ask a new question specific to tts providing the audio file and whatever you might need to replicate the issue, for now I'll accept your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things in play here.

The first is that "1:00" isn't a number. What it is depends on how you want to interpret it. If this was for entity type `@sys.time`, you could consider it a time, for example, and it would fit into one slot.

Dialogflow seems be trying to be helpful with the slot filling, which is usually intended to fill in gaps in user entry, rather than have to prompt for them. So if it *can* fill values into a parameter, it does. In this case, it sees "1:00", it needs to fill in two numbers, so it does so.

How you fix this depends on what you're trying to do. If the entity type is really a time, use `@sys.time` or something similar. If it is a string that you need to parse, then `@sys.any` might be more appropriate.

If this really should be a number - what would you expect "1:00" to do? Discard the ":00" part? Ignore it completely?

In a worst case, you may need to just prompt for each of them yourself manually instead of trying to use slot filling. This gives you more flexibility in how you handle the inputs.

It isn't clear why the speech-to-text is turning a number utterance into a time unless you also have something else that is expecting a time. If this is the issue - this is the bigger problem, and something to examine.

Comment: None of my slots are `@sys.time`, I have no idea why speech2text behaves like that, anyway, you are right in saying I can't expect much converting "1:00" to int, what I did not expect at all was it filling multiple slots. Because of the way the dialog flow console is designed (it lets you specify a prompt for each required slot) I was lead to belive it would only take one at a time. I haven't thought about using `@sys.any`, this way at least I have the chance to parse it properly in the fulfillment. I'll wait a bit more for other possible answers but this will likely be the accepted one.